Unit Testing Angular: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp')
I'm trying to develop a test for a component of an Angular (v18) application.
The component is standalone and the file spec file is the autogenerated one, I added only the services that the component use.
Do you know how to solve this error that I get?
Chrome 128.0.0.0 (Windows 10) DashboardComponent should create FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp')
            at getComponentDef (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:1563:18)
            at isStandaloneComponent (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:1559:17)
            at forEach (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:1322:29)
            at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
            at queueTypesFromModulesArrayRecur (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:1317:34)
            at forEach (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:1323:29)
            at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
            at queueTypesFromModulesArrayRecur (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:1317:34)
            at TestBedCompiler.queueTypesFromModulesArray (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:1332:9)
            at TestBedCompiler.configureTestingModule (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:833:18)
Chrome 128.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 1 of 29 (1 FAILED) (skipped 28) (0.124 secs / 0.105 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 0 SUCCESS


it could be several things. maybe DashboardComponent depends on other components that depend on other components. then you have to import all dependant component or better yet mock those components. Other thing that you can check if your component is properly initialized before using it. try to use debugger to find our where is your error exactly.

I just found a circular dependency, thanks all

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
